# lenovo g500s not booting on power and battery light still on

Tags: windows-8, boot, lenovo-laptop

my lenovo g500s with 4g ram and its running windows 8.1, last time it was 7% charge and there is pending update. so switched it of and plug the charger after like 10min, after like 18hours I tried to boot it up but it wont boot and the two lights they are still on.please i need help!

Comment: try: unplug charger, remove battery, wait a few minutes, reinstall battery, plug in charger. try turning on now

Comment: still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your charger is dead/dying. If you don't have access to a multimeter to test voltage coming out of the charger you could go buy a replacement universal charger and see if your results improve. If that doesn't work you may have an issue with your power socket on your laptop (where your charger plugs in).

Comment: i tried to charge another laptop and its working fine, i just bought my laptop last year November, its new I don't know whats going on with it.

Comment: In that case it'd be wise to submit a ticket for it with Lenovo as it'd still be under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have got same problem tried to remove the battery and press the power button for 20 sec and turn on system with ac.. This did not work. Its 6 month old lap and I have faced this problem more than 6 times..is it motherboard problem..

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to motherboard problem it's related to Windows boot manager. I was facing this issue from last 6 moths  and countered that this occurs only when windows want to update itself and battery is low.

Every one must be aware there are some drives requires at least 20 % battery and charger plugged in but this case it is returning false. So once the system start installing the updates it stucks on lenovo screen and then you will have to wait till the battery is drained and then remove the battery and just plugg in the charger and start your system (note: if you will try to change your battery and try to switch on your system is gonna again stuck on the same lenovo screen so let that 7-10% drain and then plug in the charger ).

I will try to update other information on how to get low battery out of this situation but what I simply did was uninstall the battery drivers with battery out of the tray and then restarting my system with battery in this accepted the new battery certificate and the issue got resolved for ever.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to be less like a wall of text?